# Loop to continue to process after error

Tags: r, function, loops

Ok lets say I have a directory of files and I want to run the same commands over each and every file. There is for example 10 files in my directory as below, although here will express as a list of data frames:

```
    # Create dummy files 
    file1 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))
    file2 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))
    file3 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))
    file4 <- as.data.frame(runif(12, 0,100))
    file5 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))
    file6 <- as.data.frame(runif(15, 0,100))
    file7 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))
    file8 <- as.data.frame(runif(8, 0,100))  # This is the df that its intended to fail on
    file9 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))
    file10 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))
    file11 <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0,100))

    # Lets pretend the files are .csv files on my HDD
    # But here will make a list of data frames
    file.list <- list(file1,file2,file3,file4,file5,file6,file7,file8,file9,file10)

# Rename column names for all 10 df
Names <- function(x) {
  names(x) <- c("Close")
  return(x)
}
# Apply name change to all 10 data frames
file.list <- lapply(file.list, Names)
```

Ok so now we have the data at which i want to iterate through and on each file I wish to calculate 2 to 12 simple moving average.

First will wrap the simple moving average procedure in a function starting from file.list[[i]] (or data frame 1). In my real problem these are files on my directory but for example sake its the same thing!

```
# Create function for performing commands.
    genSMA = function(x){
      nextfile <- data.frame(file.list[[i]],stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      new.df <- data.frame(nextfile)
      # Load packages 
      require(TTR)
      # Use TTR package to create rolling SMA n day moving average 
      getSMA <- function(numdays) {
        function(new.df) {
          SMA(new.df[,"Close"], numdays)    # Calls TTR package to create SMA
        }
      }
      # Create a matrix to put the SMAs in
      sma.matrix <- matrix(nrow=nrow(new.df), ncol=0)
      tail(sma.matrix)
      # Loop for filling it
      for (i in 2:12) {
        sma.matrix <- cbind(sma.matrix, getSMA(i)(new.df))
      }

      # Rename columns
      colnames(sma.matrix) <- sapply(2:12, function(n)paste("close.sma.n", n, sep=""))

      # Bind to existing dataframe
      new.df <-  cbind(new.df, sma.matrix)

    }
```

Now I call the for loop to run this function over all data frames:

```
for (i in 1:length(file.list)){
  genSMA(file.list[[i]])
}
```

Ok this is setup in order for it to fail. It should fail on data frame 8 and also print this error message:

```
 Error in runSum(x, n) : n = 9 is outside valid range: [1, 8]
```

This is because there is not enough data to compute the simple moving averages of SMA 9,10,11,12. To compute those we need data longer than 9,10,11,12 data points.

My question is:

How do I add something in this code that will continue to loop through the rest of the files and ignore the error message?

I also do not know how to save the output to one data frame? You will notice this will just run and not store the output anywhere as im not quite sure how to code that either. It would be good to store the final result in on data frame also.

However, the code above does run and for illustration purposes of showing the error message on file 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tryCatch` blocks in R:

```
for (i in 1:length(file.list)){
   tryCatch({
      genSMA(file.list[[i]])
   }, error = function(e) { print(paste("i =", i, "failed:")) })
}
```

Comment: Ok that tells me which iteration failed, on failure, will it also continue to loop through the rest of the files?

Comment: Yes why don't you test it ?

Comment: Yes is the answer - In the above example, is there a procedure for storing the output to a data frame for viewing after the process has completed?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to tryCatch, one option you should consider is the `foreach` package in R. The reason I suggest this, is because I notice you're using your for loop to build your `sma.matrix`. It is not a good idea to build an object in this way because it can become very slow very quickly because R has to keep re-allocating memory at each loop. Many people would suggest using one of the `apply` functions for this, or allocating your empty matrix in advance, but I tend to find the `foreach` package easier to use and also handles your problem of errors quite nicely:

```
library(foreach)

sma.matrix <- foreach(
  i = 1:12,        # This is your for loop iterator
  .combine=cbind,  # Specify how to combine the results of each loop
  .errorhandling="remove" # When error occurs, skip to next iteration
) %do% { # You can use %dopar% for parallel loop execution
    getSMA(i)(new.df)
}
```

Comment: Scott - thanks for the comments. This is specifically for the loop to make the SMA's to speed it up? I do the SMA procedure for EVERY file + a whole other bunch of commands, this can be integrated with the rest of my code?

Comment: Foreach can be used to replace any for loop. I find it most useful when you either (1) want to parallelise the loop, or (2) use a loop to build a object/matrix/table

Comment: Great - I will check out the package! :)